# Can i find the path of particular file (Activity or xml file) usign layout inspector tool in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inspector

I have this huge project to work on, but I don't know where certain XML files or activities are located.

I was wondering is it possible to find the path of a file using the layout inspector tool of the android studio because as it gives the live preview of the activity we are in

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

> Right-click on a particular layout file in Android Studio
> and popup come tap on Find Usages.

Comment: what? see i have open a layout in layout inspector, now i want to jump to that particular xml out of 100's of xml, now issue is when i click on ID attribute and below it the link is showing unknown:? , i think due to multiple xml having same id, so tell me how to jump to that particular xml? your answer is saying right click on particular layout file, but issue is i want to find that particular layout file.